# Remove all the rows having same column values of another column which is duplicated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

1.Input: we have a dataframe

```
ID name
1   a
1   b
2   a
2   c
3   d
```

2.Now I took the first duplicate 'name' (here it is 'a' with ID as '2') value and remove the rest, **output**:

```
ID name
1   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
```

Code I used:

```
df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep='first', subset=['name'])]
```

3.Now I want to remove all the rows sharing the same 'ID' ( here the 'a' removed was having '2' as ID, so we remove all rows with '2' as ID), **Final Expected output** : so we remove [2 c]

```
ID name
1   a
1   b
3   d
```

Code I tried: But it is not working

```
dt = df.name.duplicated(keep='first')

df.loc[~df.groupby(['ID','dt']).size().reset_index().drop(columns={0})]
```

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates("ID")`?

Comment: i have made a change to the data as per my real data now

Comment: Why the row `2   c` removed ?

Comment: your logic doesn't make sense

Comment: 2 c is removed as the row 2 a was removed, now i want to remove all ID having 2. like 2 c

Comment: my whole agenda is to remove the repeated values and all the IDs of those removed duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some kind of blacklist for the ID's:

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'ID':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 'name':['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**Code:**

```
df[~df['ID'].isin(df[df['name'].duplicated()]['ID'])]
```

**Output:**

```
   ID name
0   1    a
1   1    b
4   3    d
```

---

Code simplified:

```
blacklist = df[df['name'].duplicated()]['ID']
mask = ~df['ID'].isin(blacklist)
df[mask]
```

Comment: hi, @Andreas i have made a change to the data as per my real data

Comment: and this approach wont help

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,1,2,3, 5], 'name':['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'b']})` this approach will fail

Comment: @Anubhav thanks for updateing, yould you please elaborate about the final output? Because you wrote: `3.Now I want to remove all the rows sharing the same 'ID', Final Expected output :` But in the final output the ID 1 is used twice.

Comment: @Andreas i have updated the question with more details, hope it is understandable. If not feel free to comment it out

Answer (score 0):

If the Dataframe is ordered by ID those two approaches should work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3], 'name': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd']})

df1 = df.loc[~df.duplicated(keep='first', subset=['ID'])]
df2 = df1.loc[~df1.duplicated(keep='first', subset=['name'])]
print(df2)

print(df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', subset=['ID']).drop_duplicates(keep='first', subset=['name']))

   ID name
0   1    a
3   2    c
4   3    d
```

If it's order by name you should do subset=['name'] and then subset=['ID'].

Comment: stefan please check the data frame once again, the data was changed  a while back for better understanding